# C# Invalid URI: The URI is empty

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Hello i'm trying to collect all data from website.

On start i collecting all links on that website. After that accessing them.
The problem is when i accessing multiple pages of website the "Invalid URI: The URI is empty" error is showing in some pages. These are some of those failed urls.

```
http://syayoyu.com/category/zensinyokudiet
http://syayoyu.com/fruitgranola-6759.html
http://syayoyu.com/category/diet/fruitgranola
```

Accessing from browser and accessing them one by one is working ok. But when i try to access in loop the error is occuring. Would you please tell me what is wrong with it.

This is my accessing code

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.UserAgent = "A .NET Web Crawler";
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string htmlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Where is the loop? And what is the value of your `url` variable? Did you debug your code?

Comment: For starters, change your user agent and also, limit the number of calls you make to the same server. If you are making too many requests, the server might start blocking them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(){
@"http://syayoyu.com/category/zensinyokudiet",
@"http://syayoyu.com/fruitgranola-6759.html",
@"http://syayoyu.com/category/diet/fruitgranola"
};
foreach (var url in list)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    request.UserAgent = "A .NET Web Crawler";
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    //Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    //StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    //string htmlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    //Console.WriteLine(htmlText);
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string htmlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(htmlText);
        }
    }
}
```

In my solution, it works fine,so is there any questions you don't know?

Comment: sorry for long time to wait. I just used it result is same. Working on one by one or loop through few links is ok. But fails in big automatically addable list.